# variable not updating when executing bash code in makefile

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile that contains some bash commands in order to collect the names of the cpp files from a folder.

```
SRC_FILES=""

CC = g++

CFLAGS = -g

gather-files:
    for var in $$(cd ./src && (ls -all *.cpp | awk '{print $$9}')); \
    do                                                              \
        SRC_FILES+="./src/"+"$(var) ";                              \
    done;                                                           \

game: gather-files
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES)
```

The **SRC_FILES** and **var** variables seems not to update when I run the **make game** command.

What am I missing?

Ignore the relatively incomplete g++ command, I just want to know how to make the **SRC_FILES** variable contain all of the names of the cpp files in the **src** folder.

[image]

This is the output of **make game**:

```
g++ -c -g ""
clang: error: no input files
```

**LATER EDIT:**
Solution, as suggested:

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

CC = g++

CFLAGS = -g

game: $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text.

Comment: Edited question accordingly, now code can be copied and tested

Comment: Using `make` to deliberately compile all files seems kind of contrary to one of the points of using `make` in the first place.

Comment: Makefile is still at the beginning of creation, the trouble is only with the shell code that I wrote in it. I'm still a beginner and I'm not sure I get your point. What's the typical scenario for using make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing shell commands with makefile commands.  That's not valid.  The *entire* recipe is sent to the shell to be run there.  Once the recipe has been expanded (which happens once before the shell is invoked) the results cannot contain any make operations.

In short, it's not possible (technically it can be done but it's A Very Bad Idea (tm) so don't) to change *make* variables from within a *shell* recipe.

Why don't you use GNU make operations instead?

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

game: $(SRC_FILES)
        ...
```

Of course, this is kind of a silly makefile because it will recompile ALL the source files if ANY source file changes.  You could get equivalent behavior by just writing a script that ran the compiler.

Comment: It indeed worked when using the code you suggested. However, I'm not sure I understand why it is silly to do such a thing, could you please elaborate?

Comment: The goal of a makefile is to perform the least amount of work that reliably produces the result you want.  If you only have a few source files and it takes a few seconds to recompile them all and link them, then it's not a big deal to do that every time.  It saves having to think about which ones have been changed since the last time you compiled: you just always rebuild everything.  To do this you don't need a makefile: you could just have a shell script that ran the compiler with all the source files.  Or even a shell alias: you don't even need a separate script.

Comment: But, if you have 5,000 source files then recompiling ALL of them whenever any one changes is clearly a big waste of time and resources.  This is why make exists: it allows you to determine which source files changed and only recompile _those_ files, then link all the previously compiled code with that one newly compiled file.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Last Edit' is still not ideal, as it builds everthing every time.   Try something like this:

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o)
DEP_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.d)

#Important: this is =, not := 
DEP_FLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

game: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES)

# Pattern rule to build .o files
$(OBJ_FILES): %.o : %.cpp %.d
     $(CC) $(DEP_FLAGS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#dummy rule to prevent building .d files explicitly.
$(DEP_FILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEP_FILES))
```

As to what this does -- it first populates `SRC_FILES` with any cpp files it finds.  It then generates a list of object and dependency files from that list.   Then we do some magic dependency stuff, which is described [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) -- basically, when you compile a file, it generates a .d file with a list of all headers it depends on, so now, if anything changes, make knows to rebuild the .c file.

Then there's a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) to build all the .o files, and a rule to link them all together to the game.   Last, but not least, it includes the `DEP_FILES` that happen to exist when you start make.